# Maximize image on webpage using CSS and HTML

Tags: html, image, css, resize

I've been trying to create a (very ugly) page that resizes images depending on the width of the screen. The goal is to maximize the images so that they are all equal in size.

So far I've managed to do this for two "cells", but for some reason the other images won't resize. All I'm allowed to use is HTML(5) and CSS. Can you point me in the right direction please?

**Update:** On request added jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mNSLw/

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
  background-color:#0D8A02;
  text-align:center;
  color: #FFFB00;
}
table
{
  text-align:center;
  border: 2px solid #FFFFFF
}
div.img
{
  margin: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #FFFB00;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}   
div.img img
{
  display: inline;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 7px solid #FFFB00;
}
div.img a:hover img 
{
  border: 7px solid #FB00FF;
}
div.desc
{
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 5px;
}

.tablex
{
  display:table;
  border-left:5px solid #93FFA4;
  border-right:5px solid #93FFA4;
  text-align:center;
}

.tableheadx
{
  border-top:10px solid #93FFA4;
  border-bottom:10px solid #93FFA4;
  text-align:center;
}

.tablerowx
{
  display:table-row;
  border:3px solid #ff0000;
  text-align:center;
}

.tablecellx
{
  display:table-cell;
  text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="tablex">
    <div class="tablerowx">
      <div class="tableheadx">Informatie over Bassano del Grappa</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tablerowx">
      <div class="tablerowx"> 
        <div class="tablecellx">
          <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis2_big.htm"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/klematis_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90" /></a>
            <div class="desc">Ad feugait nostrud lobortis in illum in duis ea nonummy in minim iusto in dignissim. Aliquam feugiat facilisis suscipit ex velit laoreet molestie ut feugait. Lobortis molestie, exerci blandit quis, luptatum tincidunt vero eros luptatum dolore tation erat euismod, ad. Iriure illum dolore qui, velit ullamcorper augue dolore, vel iusto duis lorem nisl enim dolore et eros nulla aliquip. Praesent vel praesent ex feugiat     dolor nostrud eu amet delenit et erat qui iusto, commodo consequat, consequat feugiat. </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display:table-cell">
          <div class="tablecellx">
            <div class="img">
              <a target="_blank" href="http://www.w3schools.com/css/klematis2_big.htm"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/klematis_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90" /></a>
              <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tablecellx">
            <div class="img">
              <a target="_blank" href="http://www.w3schools.com/css/klematis2_big.htm"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/klematis_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90" /></a>
              <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tablerowx"> 
        <div class="tablecellx">
          <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="http://www.w3schools.com/css/klematis3_big.htm"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/klematis3_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90" /></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tablecellx">
          <table>
            <tr>
             <th>Dag</th>
             <th>Vertrektijden</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Maandag</td>
              <td>
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td>07.30</td>
                    <td>08.30</td>
                    <td>09.30</td>
                    <td>13.00</td>
                    <td>14.00</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle that displays the issue? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Will there always be three images?

Comment: No, there may be more or less images.

Comment: So (just to clarify), you want an arbitrary number of images to all have the same size, and take up the entire width of the browser window?

Answer (score 1):

I created a JSfiddle, making your HTML work: http://jsfiddle.net/s97bC/

I generated a three-column fluid layout with [Grids960](http://960.gs/), and used only the relevant parts so that you see, how it's done. 
http://grids.heroku.com/fluid_grid.css?column_amount=3

You shall remove the "display:table-whatever" parts from your code, and you might remove any unnecessary divs as well.

Comment: Sorry, is just saw the comments. If there are more than three columns in a row, you can always alter the width percentage (assuming you now it before and it is not changing dinamically, so that you are able to calculate).

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 can resize background images to the size of the screen. Is this any good to you?

```
background: url(‘mtn.jpg’) no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%; /* Gecko 1.9.2 (Firefox 3.6) */
-o-background-size: 100% 100%; /* Opera 9.5 */
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;/* Safari 3.0 */
-khtml-background-size: 100% 100%; /* Konqueror 3.5.4 */
-moz-border-image: url(mtn.jpg) 0; /* Gecko 1.9.1 (Firefox 3.5) */
```

[source](http://ioconnor.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/automatically-resizing-background-images-with-css3/)

Comment: Not entirely. I can create a new div and use the above, but then it quickly gets too big. For example:

background-size: 100% 100%;  <-- changes width-height-ratio.
background-size: 100% auto;  <-- ratio is ok, but height is wáy too large.

Answer (score 0):

Never define width of an image in pixels use percentage 100% will work on all platforms

Comment: I don't really see what you mean. Can you explain it by using http://jsfiddle.net/mNSLw/ ?

Comment: He means 18px on an iPhone 4 is a dot, but 18px on an old PC monitor is pretty big.

Comment: But that doesn't solve the problem above. I used width="90%" for the images, but it only resizes half of the current images. I don't think that changes when I set width to 100%... right?